# How to add layout header in CustomTabsIntent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using CustomTabsIntent to launch webURL in my app.

Following is my code and its working fine.

```
 CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
                .addDefaultShareMenuItem()
                .setToolbarColor(getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.light_black))
                .setShowTitle(true)
                .setStartAnimations(this,R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.no_change_animation)
                .setExitAnimations(this, R.anim.no_change_animation, R.anim.slide_in_right)

                .build();



        customTabsIntent.intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        customTabsIntent.intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(customTabsIntent.intent);
```

What i need to do is to add native layout component on the header, and side navigation hamburger in it. Something like following.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that, it is possible with a chrome custom tab or not because you are launching a chrome browser. In the Custom tab, you have limited access to modify the view.
Instead of using chrome, you can use a web view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".privacy.PrivacyActivity">

    <include
    android:id="@+id/header_layout"
    layout="@layout/header_layout" />

    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/privacy_policy_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_20"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_20"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header_layout" />
```

And the load the web URL:-

```
    private fun loadPrivacyPolicy() {
    val webView: WebView = privacy_policy_view as WebView
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/privacy.html")
    }
```

Comment: Yes but with custom tabs we can navigate between the web pages, but with webview if user presses back button he is out of view.

Comment: True. I understand your concern. I never saw any application able to do like this, custom header and chrome custom tab. Because when you are launching the custom tab, it will open the chrome application.